# Can i get a meta value with jQuery/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, metadata

Im struggling to find any information on getting meta values.

I have a locale set in the meta on a few sites and would like to use a centralised js file so i need to grab the value from say for example

```
<meta name="locale" id="locale" content="en_ZA" />
```

hmmmm....

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried `$("meta").each()`? never tried but should work.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
var m = $("meta[name=locale]");    

alert(m.attr("content"));
```

Would that suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way with example code-

```js
var content = $("meta[name=listing-page-url]").attr("content");
console.log(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta name="listing-page-url" content="demo-url" />
```