# Having information in a meta-tag that I need to extract in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-scraping, metadata

Like the title says, I have a meta-tag that I need to scrape of some information.
[Link](http://www.computer.org/csdl/letters/ca/2012/01/lca2012010001-abs.html)
It's from this site I'm trying to extract the author affiliation from. And that information can I find in the using google development tools with this line of code:

```
document.getElementsByName('citation_author_institution')
```

Then I get back what I believe is a array of elements or nodes that looks like this:

```
[<meta name=​"citation_author_institution" content=​"Columbia University, New York">​, <meta name=​"citation_author_institution" content=​"Columbia University, New York">​, <meta name=​"citation_author_institution" content=​"Columbia University, New York">​]
```

Now I need to just access the content and saving it an array so I can put it in my database.
I have tried with stuff like

```
document.getElementsByName('citation_author_institution').textContent
document.getElementsByName('citation_author_institution').getAttribute('content')
```

But that doesnt work. Anyone have any idea or tip for me how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289302/can-i-get-a-meta-value-with-jquery-js

Comment: I'd start with getElementsByTagName, really. Theoretically there may be more elements in  the HTML with the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. What you need to do is to iterate through the list of nodes:

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByName('citation_author_institution')
    var contents = []

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        contents.push(elements[i].content);
    }

    console.log(contents)
```

So, `contents` will be your list of contents. Example here 
https://jsfiddle.net/o3Lzm4ca/

Comment: But If I do like this and wont it print out all content in the array? I mean like this:

meta name=​"citation_author_institution" content=​"Columbia University, New York">​, <meta name=​"citation_author_institution" content=​"Columbia University, New York">​, <meta name=​"citation_author_institution" content=​"Columbia University, New York"

Because when I use this and try to save the result to a JSON-file, I get a message saying:

toString({\n [native code \n]})

Comment: @anderssinho Update your question to show the exact code you are running and the exact output. Read Luis' code carefully to understand the contents of the array. The array does not contain the (entire) element nor the HTML representation of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var authors = [];
var elements = document.getElementsByName('citation_author_institution');
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    authors.push(elements[i].content);
}
console.log(authors)
```

Comment: But If I do like this and wont it print out all content in the array? I mean like this:

meta name=​"citation_author_institution" content=​"Columbia University, New York">​, <meta name=​"citation_author_institution" content=​"Columbia University, New York">​, <meta name=​"citation_author_institution" content=​"Columbia University, New York"

Because when I use this and try to save the result to a JSON-file, I get a message saying:

toString({\n [native code \n]})