# how to get meta image from html source code?

Tags: jquery

**i have html data in console .... how will i find `meta tag og image` from this html source code**
**the below code is in form of string**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" id="facebook" class="no_js">
    <head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-crossorigin" id="meta_referrer" /><script>function envFlush(a){function b(c){for(var d in a)c[d]=a[d];}if(window.requireLazy){window.requireLazy(['Env'],b);}else{window.Env=window.Env||{};b(window.Env);}}envFlush({"ajaxpipe_token":"AXjKg9wJIltZEBjN","khsh":"0`sj`e`rm`s-0fdu^gshdoer-0gc^eurf-3gc^eurf;1;enbtldou;fduDmdldourCxO`ld-2YLMIuuqSdptdru;qsnunuxqd;rdoe-0unjdojnx-0unjdojnx0-0gdubi^rdbsduOdv-0`sj`e`r-0q`xm`r-0StoRbs`qhof-0mhoj^q`xm`r"});</script><style></style><script>__DEV__=0;CavalryLogger=false;</script><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/?_fb_noscript=1" /></noscript><title id="pageTitle">Facebook - Log In or Sign Up</title><meta property="og:site_name" content="Facebook" /><meta property="og:url" content="https://www.facebook.com/" /><meta property="og:image" content="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" /><meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" /><script type="application/ld+json">{"\u0040context":"http:\/\/schema.org","\u0040type":"WebSite","name":"Facebook","url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/"}
```

Comment: please indent your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i get a meta value with jQuery/JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289302/can-i-get-a-meta-value-with-jquery-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got this markup as a string, you'll need to parse it as an HTML document.
To do so, use the [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

From then, you can use normal DOM methods to go to your element and get its attribute value :

```js
var markup = `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" id="facebook" class="no_js"><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-crossorigin" id="meta_referrer" /><script>function envFlush(a){function b(c){for(var d in a)c[d]=a[d];}if(window.requireLazy){window.requireLazy(['Env'],b);}else{window.Env=window.Env||{};b(window.Env);}}envFlush({"ajaxpipe_token":"AXjKg9wJIltZEBjN","khsh":"0\`sj\`e\`rm\`s-0fdu^gshdoer-0gc^eurf-3gc^eurf;1;enbtldou;fduDmdldourCxO\`ld-2YLMIuuqSdptdru;qsnunuxqd;rdoe-0unjdojnx-0unjdojnx0-0gdubi^rdbsduOdv-0\`sj\`e\`r-0q\`xm\`r-0StoRbs\`qhof-0mhoj^q\`xm\`r"});<\/script><style></style><script>__DEV__=0;CavalryLogger=false;<\/script><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/?_fb_noscript=1" /></noscript><title id="pageTitle">Facebook - Log In or Sign Up</title><meta property="og:site_name" content="Facebook" /><meta property="og:url" content="https://www.facebook.com/" /><meta property="og:image" content="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" /><meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" /><script type="application/ld+json">{"\u0040context":"http:\/\/schema.org","\u0040type":"WebSite","name":"Facebook","url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/"}`;

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(markup, 'text/html');
var meta = doc.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
var value = meta && meta.getAttribute('content');

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add name attribute to your meta tag and then:

```
$("meta[name=og-image]").attr("content")
```